# react native, moving between screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am using stackNavigator in react native .my problem is I want to move to another screen using stack navigator.

app.js

```
    const CartStack=createStackNavigator({
      Header:Header,
      Cart:Cart
   )}
   Const Root=createStackNavigator({
      Home:Home,
      Detail:Detail,
      CartStack:CartStack,  
   )}
```

Home.js

```
 render() {
       return (
       <Header/>

   )}
```

The Header Will be show on both screens (Home and Detail)
in the header i created a cart button which i want to click on 
it then will be open a Cart screen. But my code is not working.
Please correct my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept in Zayco's answer is absolutely correct.
But I figured out that `this.props.navigation.navigate` will be `undefined` in **navigationOptions**

Here is the **[working example](https://snack.expo.io/@dhavaljardosh/react-navigation-example)** of your requirement.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Home',
    headerRight:(<Button title="Cart" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}/>)
  })
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Scree</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Details extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Details',
    headerRight:(<Button title="Cart" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}/>)
  })
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Cart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Cart</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    Details: Details,
    Cart:Cart
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the [React Navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html)

You have 3 screens: Home, Details and Cart. In the header of Home and Details you have a button that will take you to the Cart screen. I suggest you take a look at the Fundementals section of the documentation.

[Here is the working Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@zayco/bmF2aW)

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: "Home",
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
        title="Cart"
        color="blue"
      />
    )
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        title="Go to details"
        color="red"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: "Details",
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
        title="Cart"
        color="blue"
      />
    ),
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        title="Go to home"
        color="red"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class CartScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Cart Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
    Cart: CartScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```